# Why doesn't Google Now's place-specific reminders remember my home location?

Tags: geolocation, google-now

I have my home and work locations set. These show up accurately in Google Maps and also in Google Now if I go "Wand" -> "Places" at the bottom.

However, whenever I go to set a place-specific reminder, Google Now reprompts me to enter my home location. The screen looks like this:

[image: Google Now forgetting home location]

As you can see, the "Home" field doesn't actually have an address below it.

This is never remembered. How can I fix this?

Comment: Strange one. I just had same problem, however clicked on "Remind me at this place" below the dropdown, chose my home address and created a reminder. Deleted it and went to create a new one and my address was remembered.

Comment: Thanks for the response - sadly, I've added the address multiple times through this route. It seems to be lost after 24 hours